# Display file type icon in Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, sharepoint, file

I have this situation where I need to display a bunch of files pulled from a Sharepoint site in a Silverlight application. I use a WCF service to get the data from the Sharepoint site.

So what I have is file names with their corresponding extensions. What I need to do is, display the files in the Silverlight application with their corresponding file type icon and file name. The following is the Heirarchical data template I use to display the files in the Silverlight application.

```
<sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image x:Name="imgFile" Source="{Binding FileImage}" Height="35" ></Image>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtFile" Text="{Binding FileName}"></TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
  </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Where FileImage and FileName are strings.

PS: The reason I don't have file type and size is because I using Sharepoint web services and XMLReader to get the information about the files.

Comment: You haven't stated what your actual question or problem is...

Comment: @slugster.. My actual question is how to display the files in the silverlight application with their corresponding file type icons..?? I guess I have said that as What I need to do..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the obvious solution of maintaining a internal mapping of file extensions to file icons of our own, the only other solution that I can think of is that you call back to the server to get the image for the file type.

There is a native shell function called [SHGetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762179%28VS.85%29.aspx) which can provide the file info for a file. Note that if you use the SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES flag the file does not have to physically exist on the server. Of course the problem is that you will need to use P/Invoke to actually call this function since it does not exist as a managed function in the standard .NET libraries.

The following Microsoft KB article should get you started with how to call the SHGetFileInfo from .NET.
[How to use the SHGetFileInfo function to get the icons that are associated with files in Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319350)

Fro more detailed info on using P/Invoke to call SHGetFileInfo you can also see the following URL, it includes the definition of all the flags.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.SHGetFileInfo

**NB:** Because ICO files are not directly supported by silverlight, you will need a ICO image decoder. I have not tried this code my self, but you can try the code bu Joe Stegman located on his blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jstegman/archive/2009/09/13/silverlight-ico-icon-decoder-parser.aspx

Comment: @Chris.. Thanks a lot. But I have a little tricky situation here. The problem is, I am pulling the file data using my WCF service which uses Sharepoint's Lists.asmx service.. So technically, I read the serialized data to get the information about the file. So what my WCF service gives to the Silverlight application is a list of file names and file information (size, type etc.) which are basically strings. So I am not able to get the handle for the file.

Comment: Also.. I see that the Sharepoint's 12 Hive folder has all the file type icons in it. So it would be great if you / someone could tell me if there is a way to access that (through a sharepoint's service or a shell function).. Otherwise, I will have to go with mapping the file types with the images preloaded in the application.

Comment: @Aswin, I do not know Sharepoint's services so I can not help on that front, but if you make a second call to a backend which does the SHGetFileInfo call you do not require a file handle. If you use the SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES flag you only need the file extension.

Comment: @Chris.. Thanks for the info.. I haven't done shell programming before.. So will take a look at using the SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES and will let you know.. Thanks again..